# Import a standard http request in postman?

Tags: postman

I have a simple HTTP request :

```
POST /a/b/c HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:17814
Content-Type: application/json
jwt: x.x.x

{
    "requestId": "E1EC8B9E-A78E-443A-B2A9-8D6F7692B63C"
}
```

I don't have another format. It's a basic HTTP standard request structure.
I want to invoke it in Postman.

But it seems that when I try to "Import" it in postman it says :

[image]

**Question:**

Is there any way to import standard HTTP requests in postman? there must be. it's the standard syntax

Answer (score 1):

The Import feature only supports certain formats.

> Import a Postman Collection, Environment, data dump, curl command, or
>   a RAML / WADL / Open API (1.0/2.0/3.0) / GraphQL Schema / Runscope
>   file

I *guess* that would be something this in curl:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:17814/a/b/c' \
-H 'jwt: x.x.x' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "requestId": "E1EC8B9E-A78E-443A-B2A9-8D6F7692B63C"
}'
```

You can import that format into the app and it should create the request.

Comment: I know that i can import curl but i dont want to convert it each time

Comment: I must say i find it pretty strange that it accepts all advanced structures but not the plain portable structure....

Comment: I find a lot of things strange... If its something you feel is needed, you can submit a feature request.

Comment: I find it odd that you can export a request in http format in postman, but not import the same

Comment: @SamJones feature requests can be submitted via the github repo https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues